# What are the advantages of using @UiFactory to construct widgets in GWT?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

Are there any advantages (other than clean code and the like) of using @UiFactory to construct widgets as opposed to declaring them in @UiField and then making additions/changes in the code after the initWidget()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can of course use `@UiField` to let UiBinder instantiate the fields for you during `createAndBindUi()`. You can then modify them afterwards.
- You can of course use `@UiField(provided=true)`, and instantiate the fields yourself, before calling `createAndBindUi()`. (This way, you can use any constructor you like, and it also allows for Dependency Injection.) And obviously, you can still modify them after `createAndBindUi()`.

So what's the point of `@UiFactory`? Well, I use it sometimes, when I have many similar elements in the same ui.xml file. So e. g. I have a page that shows a keypad with digits 0-9. Instead of having ten @UiFields, I prefer to use @UiFactory, which constructs the widgets, and puts them in a java.util.Map (plus performs some common setup).

Comment: Great answer. Do I understand correctly that there is no difference after the code is compiled?

Comment: I wouldn't say that it results in the same code, but that the resulting code produces the same results ;-) (Plus, in my example, the benefit, that I can access the fields via a Map etc.)

Answer (score 2):

There might be parameters to your UiBinder file that can not be constructed using a simple constructor (e.g. a CssResource to share styles across many UiBinder files).
Using @UiFactory you can inject those resources into your UiBinder file.

Comment: Daniel, I understand that part, but I can also do it in Java code, like we did before UiBinder. Are there any performance, rendering, or compile advantages? Is it worth refactoring the old code that did not use UiFactory?